# How do I use server-side gzip decompression with Google Cloud Storage's Go API?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, compression

I have a file in GCS compressed with gzip, with metadata `Content-Encoding` set to `gzip`. This allows an HTTP layer to set the request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, and a conforming HTTP client with then decompress it automatically.

However, it also allows the client to ask for the file uncompressed (i.e. by not specifying `Accept-Encoding: gzip`). The decompression is then done on Google's side, wasting bandwidth.

In this case though I want to waste the bandwidth. The traffic is local to the GCP region, so bandwidth is effectively infinite, and it's free. I'm more short on CPU, since my VM is one of those low-CPU burstable ones, so I want to give the job of decompressing to Google.

If I use `gsutil`, it seems it's being clever, and it's compressed over the network.

Default with Go API shows the same behavior.

If I try to set `WithHTTPClient` to maybe unset some headers, I don't see any request headers, and also it expects me to manually add the GCS credentials.

I also tried setting `ReadCompressed` to both `true` and `false`, with no success.

The only way I manage to have it be decompressed on the Google side is by creating a signed URL, and then using `curl` to download it. That way the rate of output from curl matches the bandwidth use. In all other cases the network traffic is 10% of output from the download, showing that it's compressed during transfer.

How do I, in the Go API, say that I want the data uncompressed?

What I want to see is `slurm -i eth0` shows the same speed as my `./gcscat gs://.... | pv > /dev/null`, just like I see when I use `curl -s ... | pv > /dev/null` on a signed URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are stuck, but I tested this piece of code on my side and it works great. If the content-encoding is not set to GZIP, I get a binary content. If it's set, I get a text content;

```
import (
  "cloud.google.com/go/storage",
  "context",
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client,err :=storage.NewClient(ctx)
    fmt.Println(err)
    bucket := client.Bucket("gib-multiregion-us")
    blob := bucket.Object("gzip.blob.gz")
    reader, err := blob.NewReader(ctx)
    fmt.Println(err)
    defer reader.Close()
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(string(content))
}
```

Comment: But is it decompressed on the server? Your code is essentially identical to mine. When I do what you have here I see e.g. 20MB/s on the network (seen in `slurm`), and 200MB as I'm printing it to stdout into a `pv`. The methodology I use seems correct since I see 200MB&200MB when I use curl, as described.